# Access Data From Already Open But Not Saved Excel File In Separate Instance

Tags: vba, excel

I have two excel files in separate instances of excel. I want to take data from one instance of excel to another. This seemed simple as I know that path of the file that I want to pull data from. However, the file I want to pull data from is used by a separate program where it opens up the file I want to pull from (a template), populates it, but does not save it. So each time this external program is running it is using the file I want to pull data from but since it never saves it I am having a hard time pulling data from the template file. I have used the getObject() function which successfully pulls data from the file as I know the file path but the fields are of course empty as when the external program used the file, it only filled in the data but never saves it. How can I do what I am asking?

Comment: you can save the file in code then pull the fields :). Or `SaveAsCopy` if saving the actual file is not viable solution/

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Thank you for the reply! how to I save a copy of the workbook and ensure it is the active running workbook with the data populated by the external application? If I call SaveAsCopy with the path name won't it just save a copy of the template and not the template with the data filled in by the external application?

Answer (score 0):

Building on Scotts [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50917946/access-data-from-already-open-but-not-saved-excel-file-in-separate-instance#comment88836355_50917946)

1. Since you know the full path and name of the other workbook, use `GetObject` to reference it
2. Use `.SaveCopyAs` to save it
3. Open the saved copy in the local instance

This code goes in the file running in your instance of Excel

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim wbRemote As Workbook
    Dim wbLocal as Workbook
    ' Get reference to the workbook running in the other instance of Excel
    Set wbRemote = GetObject("C:\data\Temp\TemplateBook.xlsx")
    ' Save a copy
    wbRemote.SaveCopyAs "C:\data\Temp\Temp.xlsx"
    ' remove reference
    Set wbRemote = Nothing

    ' open copy in this instance
    Set wbLocal = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\data\Temp\Temp.xlsx")

    ' work with object wbLocal 
    ' ...

End Sub
```

Comment: Note: when I started looking at this I tried `Debug.Print wbRemote.Worksheets(1).Range("A2")` where `A2` data was manually added after the workbook was opened.  This initially didn't work, but after a few false starts it started to work.

Comment: I cannot get the above to work as I get a type mismatch error. Does it matter that my files are .xls format?